# Ionic2 google maps image layer

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I am building an Ionic2 app where I am using google maps as an orientation map and I need to put an image layer on top of the map. I am trying to put building layout image over the building complex in Google maps. 
I found this solution for javascript here, which is exactly what I need: [Google maps js API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple)

I am quite new to Ionic2 and Anglular2 and having no luck figuring it out so far.

**Any advice appreciated**

My code :

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';


declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html'
})
export class MapPage {

 @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
 map: any;
 
 lat : any ;
 lng : any ;
 

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,  public geolocation: Geolocation) {
    this.getGeoLocation();
   
  }

 initializeMap() {
    var minZoomLevel = 17;
    
      let mapOptions = 
      {
        zoom: minZoomLevel,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions); 
  }

  getGeoLocation(){
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
      this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
      this.initializeMap();
      
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently it was easier than I thought. You just define image boundaries and create an instance of an overlay and then add it to the map like this...

```
var oldBuilding = {
      north: 53.27959,
      west: -9.01287,
      south: 53.278038,
      east: -9.00876
    }; 
this.oldBuildingOverLay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay('../assets/Map.png', oldBuilding);
this.oldBuildingOverLay.setMap(this.map);
```

Declare `oldBuildingOverlay: any;` and you're up and running.